# C++ SFML texture and sprite in class (white box)

Tags: c++, sfml

So i'm looking for an answer about 1 month and no one can't figure out what is going on. I have class GameObject which have sprite and texture in it, and when i call function ->getSprite() and draw it on my window i get only white box. I retyped my code 3 times again and i have the same problem again and again. I will be so happy if someone help me with this. Here are my files. [files](http://pastebin.com/pUFpKKiu)

Comment: You could start by adding a few logs, to track the loading of the PNG file

Comment: And btw i just started with c++

Comment: Sounds like there is some issue with your code. Where is it? (Please see [ask] before responding.)

Comment: Here is link of my code http://pastebin.com/pUFpKKiu

Comment: I was having problem with pointers but i fixed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had the SAME problem.
I struggled with loading a texture (.png), but I made a function where you simply give it the source (as a string) and than it returns the valid sf::Sprite.

```
//loads a graphic from a source
static sf::Sprite loadSprite(std::string source){
    static sf::Texture t;
    if (!t.loadFromFile(source)){
        std::cerr << "Error: File couldn't be loaded" << std::endl;
    }
    static sf::Sprite s;
    s.setTexture(t);
    return s;
}
```

Try to make this function for GameObject.h available (and maybe other files,too).
To use it, simply add a

```
void setSprite(std::string source){
    sprite = loadSprite(source); //call that function
}
```

function into one of your GameObject.h public member functions, wich you can also call from the constructor.
Try it out! Good luck

Comment: OMG you are my HERO

Comment: OMG. FINALY After 1 month

Comment: Do you know why that method works?

Comment: static forces that all variables STAY. I noticed that, the relation between sprite and texture is a pointer-like relation. So once one partner is thrown away, white box. Idk why, but they programmed it like that.
Ps: I am really glad I helped you and I would be really happy if you upvoted my comment. :)

Comment: I'm new on stackoverflow. That's the least thing I can do for you. And thank you very very much, you saved my time.